# Running ASP.NET on Mono Resource Access Errors

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, asp.net-4.0

***Summary of Solutons***: The core issue was that I had my resx files in subfolders within App_LocalResources and App_GlobalResources. Separating things into folders is fine on .NET but Mono only looks at the files in those folders ignoring any sub folders.

Issue #2 works only at runtime. In other words the Resources namespace can be used in the aspx or in code in a script block in the page but not in the code behind. It seems that I've never used the Resources namespace in the code-behind proper so all 3 of my issues are solved.

---

I have an ASP.NET application I was previously working on on .NET on a PC and am trying to move over to a Mac to develop using Mono and MonoDevelop. The application utilizes the App_GlobalResources and App_LocalResources folders. The application worked on .NET but does not function properly on Mono as I will outline. The version information is below:

OS: Mac OS 10.8.2
Mono: 2.10.9
ASP.NET: 4.0.30319.1
MonoDevelop: 3.0.5

I've tagged this with MonoDevelop because I'm not sure what server is being used and whether it is a part of MonoDevelop or Mono itself or is separate. I'm not familiar enough yet with Mono and it's parts...

The issues I'm having revolve around accessing resources and I'm having various related issues which I'll outline below:

**Issue 1: meta:resourcekey doesn't work and "a resource object was not found at the specified virtualPath." error**

I have App_LocalResources folders and resx files for each page at the root of the application as well as in sub-folders where page localization is required. Elements on the page that have a meta:resourcekey attribute do not have the relevant property assigned the value in the resx file.

So for example I have: /Site/Home.aspx with a /Site/App_LocalResources/Home folder which contains home.aspx.resx and related translations

N.B. as I was writing this I realised the names don't match up with regards the files case, but that is not the issue, I've tested with another page in the same folder and it doesn't render out the resource values.

The page in question has no code behind.

A different page in the root of the application called PageNotFound.aspx has related resx files in /App_LocalResources/PageNotFound/PageNotFound.aspx.resx

This page content is basically as follows (if I remove both the page renders)

```
<h2><asp:Literal runat="server" meta:resourcekey="PageNotFound" /></h2>
<% string message = GetLocalResourceObject("Sorry.Template").ToString(); %>
```

I get the same error whether I remove the first or the second of these lines. The error starts:

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: A resource object was not 
found at the specified virtualPath at
System.Web.Compilation.DefaultResourceProvider.GetLocalResourcesAssembly
```

If I remove the first line is actually builds and tries to render the page but crashes giving the above error.

If I remove the second line I get the error as well but it is while the page is being parsed and the runtime is trying to build the page class.

So for one page is seems build and run with meta:resourcekey attributes but isn't binding the resource value to the properties of the underlying controls, on another page it seems to crash trying to access the resources. The odd thing is the page that crashes is a very simple page without a master page and it basically only has the above content, the other page is quite complex with a master page and it renders (i.e. no parser error) but without the resourcekey values assigned....

The only differences that I can see are that one page is in the root directory and no master page, the other is in a sub folder and has a master page? Go figure! Any ideas?

**Issue 2: Resources namespace doesn't exist**

If I access a page that uses the 'Resources' namespaces that is available in .NET, I get a runtime compilation error, as in the app builds when compiled, but as the page is parsed and compiled it causes a (runtime) exception...

```
Compilation Error: CS0103: The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context
```

The code would be in the code behind: (***EDIT***: The following line I think, was me testing, my code never uses this namespace in a code behind (compile time) class. Once the global resources functioned then the namespaces worked at runtime, but not in scenarios where the namespace needs to be verified at compile time as outlined in the summary at the top of the question)

```
msg.Subject = Resources.EmailResources.Request_SubjectLine
```

or in a script block in the aspx itself i.e.

```
<%= Resources.EmailResources.Request_SubjectLine %>
```

Neither of these types of access to the Resources namespace work. Why does this not work in Mono. Does the Mono framework not generate this stuff for us like .NET does? (I'm fairly sure this namespace hierarchy is generated by the ASP.NET framework on .NET and therefore wonder if this just has not been implemented in Mono?)

**Issue 3: GetGlobalResourceObject(...) Call Returns Null**

In the code-behind I have calls to GetGlobalResourceObject() which works on .NET, but when I run it on Mono my code is throwing an exception. For example:

```
hlContact.Text = GetGlobalResourceObject("CommonResources", "Contact").ToString();
```

My folder structures is:
App_GlobalResources > CommonResources > CommonResources.resx and the designer file (CommonResources.Designer.cs) is there.

The resx files are all marked with build action of "EmbeddedResource", "Do not copy" use the Custom Tool "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator" and have a resource ID that makes sense for each file. (i.e. .App_GlobalResources.CommonResources)

The issue is that GetGlobalResourceObject() returns null... It's not finding the CommonResources resource....

Note that Mono is constructing '*.resource' files in the folder with the resx files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue #1**

Apparently mono doesn't search subdirectories for resources, that is you must keep them directly in `App_LocalResources` or `App_GlobalResources`. See the [relevant part in the mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AppResourceFilesCollection.cs#L134) (line 134). If searching subdirectories is an official feature, then this is a bug, and can be easily fixed by changing the aforementioned line.

---

**Issue #2**

Works fine here (on linux).

---

**Issue #3**

I don't know how exactly you are embedding the resources, a small test project would help. For the `App_GlobalResources` the framework compiles them at runtime and then `GetGlobalResourceObject` works fine too.

Comment: Yup! That was the issue... Moved App_GlobalResources resx files out of their sub folders and same with the App_LocalResources resx files and both #1 and #3 were resolved for the main test page I was using! 

Issue #2 doesn't work oddly. Will have to look into that one a bit more. I suppose. 

#1 and #2 solve basically 95% of my problems so #2 is not that big an issue. Though if you say it works (on Linux) then it likely should work here too?)

Thank you for putting your time into this rather long-winded question!

Comment: Issues #2 worked in the aspx, but I thought that you could use it in the code-behind, seems you can't and I've never used it in the code-behind but only in script blocks in the aspx itself (c# script blocks I mean) so thats 100% of my issues solved, and something vague clarified. Thanks again! :)